# Excel, VBA: Repeat graph number of times

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create graph that takes my points and repeats them n-times.

EDIT:
**The one segment can be more than 200K points, so solution with copying of points n-times is not correct!**
END OF EDIT

Example:
My points are (0,0), (1,1), (2,2), (3,1), (4,0)
It's looks like so:

**Triangle wave segment in Excel**
[image]

In VBA I need to repeat all those points, with X-axis changes, n-times to get the next result:

**Triangle wave**
[image]

EDIT:
My VBA code:

```
Sub CreateChart()
    'PURPOSE: Create a chart (chart dimensions are not required)

    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim cht As Object
    Dim aTitle As String
    Dim bTitle As String

    aTitle = Range("A1").Value
    bTitle = Range("B1").Value
        Range("A1").Clear
        Range("B1").Clear
    'Your data range for the chart
      Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:B6")

    'Create a chart
      Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2

    'Give chart some data
      cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng1

      'cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng1

    'Determine the chart type
      cht.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines

      Range("A1").Value = aTitle
      Range("B1").Value = bTitle


End Sub
```

Comment: Okay, do you have some code that you want us to look at then?

Comment: I'm absolutely don't know how can I do it...
I'll add my code and Excel print screen to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm feeling nice, so here's something that will generate the data you need. You input the number of data points you want, and the cell where you want the top-left of the data to be.

```
Sub TriangleWave(numPoints As Long, startCell As range)
    Dim i As Long, j As Integer, increment As Integer
    j = 0
    increment = 1
    For i = 0 To numPoints - 1
        startCell.Offset(i, 0).value = i
        startCell.Offset(i, 1).value = j
        j = j + increment
        If j = 2 Then
            increment = -1
        ElseIf j = 0 Then
            increment = 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Sub ExampleUsage()
    TriangleWave 300000, range("TempData!A1")
End Sub
```

Just select this data and go to Insert | Charts | Scatter and select a solid-line scatter graph.

Comment: Thank you, but what if one my segment takes more than 200K points?
I need another solution :(

Comment: I edited it. You can specify any number of points up to about 1,000,000 which is approaching the worksheet size limit in Excel.

Comment: Charts in Excel use data from within the worksheet, so you cannot avoid creating the data before you produce a chart.

Comment: @Archimaredes That's not entirely accurate. You *can* use static values for a chart, but you will quickly run into the length limit for a SERIES formula if you have a lot of points, or a lot of decimal places in your values.

Comment: @Michael The code works in my workbook. Where does the syntax error occur? (Bear in mind that the ExampleUsage sub points to a worksheet named TempData.)

Comment: @Archimaredes - Ups, sorry! Works now... But as mentioned above, not what I'm searching for :(( Not sure that it's possible in Excel...

Comment: @Michael I see - you want to repeat whatever points you have listed, not just the particular pattern you showed in your question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Archimaredes No :) It prints all points... You know what?! May be I'll use it, with little tuning... If it will work, I'll make your answer as right :)

Comment: @Michael Yes it prints all points - as Rory says, the only way you could possibly avoid this is by having a much smaller data set. You could always put this data into a hidden worksheet.

Comment: @Archimaredes, so, up to 1M points it will work. Thanks a lot! Mark your answer as a right answe :)